# Angular Reactive Forms multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two input tags of different files like one is for image and the next one is for pdf file inside a form with is reactive for validation everything works as expected but the last input tag is always null and the form is invalid if I remove one input tag then it works as expected.

```
<form
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        [formGroup]="reactiveForm"
        (ngSubmit)="submit()"
      >
        <h3>Add New Magazine</h3>
        <div class="form-group p-2">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Magazine Name</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Magazine Name"
            required
            formControlName="magazineName"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group p-2">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Magazine Month & year</label>
          <br />
          <div class="input-group">
            <input
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
              name="dp"
              ngbDatepicker
              formControlName="publishDate"
              #d="ngbDatepicker"
            />
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button
                class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                (click)="d.toggle()"
                type="button"
              >
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group p-2">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Magazine Brand</label>
          <br />
          <div class="form-group">
            <select
              class="custom-select"
              required
              formControlName="magazineBrand"
            >
              <option value="">Open this select menu</option>
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
              <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group p-2">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Magazine Thumbnail Image</label>
          <br />
          <label
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block"
            for="my-file-selector"
          >
            <input
              formControlName="thumbnailFile"
              id="my-file-selector"
              type="file"
              (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
              name="image"
              accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
              style="display: none"
            />
            <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            &nbsp; Browse: Upload a Photo
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group p-2">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Upload Magazine PDF</label>
          <br />
          <label
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block"
            for="my-file-selector"
          >
            <input
              formControlName="pdfFile"
              id="my-file-selector"
              type="file"
              (change)="onPDFFileSelected($event)"
              name="image"
              accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
              style="display: none"
            />
            <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            &nbsp; Browse: Upload a Photo
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group p-2">
          <button
            [disabled]="reactiveForm.invalid"
            class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"
          >
            <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Save
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div
            *ngIf="loadingIndicator"
            class="spinner-border text-success form-group p-2"
            role="status"
          >
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

if I remove one input tag from the above then the form is valid and it enables button for submission

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reactiveForm = this.builder.group({
      magazineName: [null, [Validators.required]],
      publishDate: [null, Validators.required],
      magazineBrand: [null, [Validators.required]],
      thumbnailFile: [null, Validators.required],
      pdfFile: [null, Validators.required],
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PDF files input's label is using the same id as that of the thumbnail input. Assign different id's to each input and then associate your labels with them respectively:

```
<label
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block"
            for="my-file-selector">
            <input
              formControlName="thumbnailFile"
              id="my-file-selector"
              type="file"
              (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
              name="image"
              accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
              style="display: none"/>
            <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            &nbsp; Browse: Upload a Photo
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group p-2">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Upload Magazine PDF</label>
          <br />
          <label
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block"
            for="my-file-selector2"
          >
            <input
              formControlName="pdfFile"
              id="my-file-selector2"
              type="file"
              (change)="onPDFFileSelected($event)"
              name="image"
              accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
              style="display: none"
            />
            <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            &nbsp; Browse: Upload a Photo
          </label>
        </div>
```

**Explaination**

`<label>` can be associated with a single `<input>` through `for` attribute e.g

```
<label for="imageInput">Image Input</label>
<input id="imageInput">
```

As you already know, once associated, your label will act the same as the file input when clicked. Now let say we have two inputs, we will define them as following:

```
<label for="imageInput">Image Input</label>
<input id="imageInput">

<label for="pdfInput">PDF Input</label>
<input id="pdfInput">
```

Each input has unique id and is having a single label associated to it through that id. The reason you were getting error is because you were using same id, for both labels, in Our case:

```
  <label for="imageInput">Image Input</label>
<input id="imageInput"/>

<label for="imageInput">PDF Input</label>
<input id="pdfInput"/>
```

Note that both  `for` attributes are having the same value `imageInput`. what happens now is that when you click the second lable (PDF Input), it will act on behalf of `imageInput` input instead of `pdfInput`.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: you are right, but the problem is not about the type of file but it something that it did set the value of pdfFile as it does for thumbnailFile

Comment: I didn't understand your last statement but if your accept attribute is set to accept only images then it's not gonna hold the value for a PDF file

Comment: okay, even if  i'm accepting images then the pdfFile is always null and thumbnailFile got it's value from the input that is same as pdfFile it looks like form angular only allow to me a single input field that will accept multiple or single on one go.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yg1e8y?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: please check this is out you will get pdfFile is null always

Comment: Thanks for stackblitz, I was gonna create one. Let me have a look